# how to create custom section like Post, Media?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm kinda new to Wordpress, and I want to create a custom section like Post, Media...

If anyone knows how to do that, hit me with hints or links to that, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope below link helps you :
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/complete-guide-custom-post-types/

Comment: thanks, man I was kinda struggling to find a way to this, that is a great resource